# PHP Timezone conversion fails

Tags: php, timezone, utc

I have to convert the local time to a new time using a given timezone
The problem is that the timezone is not in this format: `'Europe/Bucharest'` but in this one: `'EEST'` (which stands for Eastern European Summer Time)

Is there any way of converting from a time to another using just the abbreviations (EEST, EST) ?

Thank you

Comment: EEST isn't really a time zone. There are fundamental problems with converting values using the abbreviations, and you should avoid them if you possibly can. Where are you getting the abbreviation from, and can you possibly do anything to get a real time zone ID instead?

Comment: The only other info about EEST that I have is the full name: `Eastern European Summer Time`, the location `Europe` and the timezone `UTC + 3 hours`

Comment: Where are the values coming from? Basically, there are several places where all of those could apply, and they won't all have the same history...

Comment: Yeah, you are right about this. I just checked the DB and for EEST there are 3 entries (Africa, Asia and Europe). And as far as I saw these abbreviations, although they have the same name, they might have different offsets. Guess I am going to populate my db with 'America/New_York', 'Europe/Bucharest' and so on ....